# How can I change the time format used in my MVC Razor code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my C# code I have a datatype of

```
public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
```

In my razor code this prints out as:

```
<td>@Model.Created</td>

5/23/2012 1:26:39 PM
```

I would like to change the format to:

```
5/23/2012 13:26
```

Can someone help me by telling me how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

you should call the toString method and pass the mask to it

```
<td>@Model.Created.toString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")</td>
```

Comment: error CS1061: 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' does not contain a definition for 'toString' and no extension method 'toString' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I think this will crash because it will use the `ToString` on the Nullable, which doesn't have an overload which takes a string.

Comment: You should check if the @Model.Created is not null. like yuriy-faktorovich sugested

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use

```
@Model.Created.Value.ToString(myFormat);
```

Where *myFormat* is a format string

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4

For the specific format you're looking for try the *myFormat* string "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm".  Specifically the "H" will give you a 24-hour clock rather than am/pm formatting.  HH ensures that the 24-hour clock is padded with a leading 0 if needed.

If *Created* can ever be null, be sure and check whether it is and output something appropriate.

You can create an extension method that acts on a nullable DateTime, outputting either something appropriate if the value is null, else applying the DateTime with your formatting applied.

```
    public static IHtmlString DateFormatted(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, DateTime? dateTime, string format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")
    {
        string formatted = dateTime.HasValue ? dateTime.Value.ToString(format) : ("(null)");

        return new HtmlString(formatted);
    }
```

Use the extension method like this

```
<td>@Html.DateFormatted(Model.Created)</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Model.Created.HasValue? Model.Created.Value.ToString("M/d/yyyy H:mm") : "Not Created"
```

Comment: error CS1501: No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Comment: @Anne Did you try that latest version? I added the `.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this more than once or globally, you can create a DateTime.cshtml template in the Shared/DisplayTemplates folder and have it contain the format string shown in the other answers. For example:

```
@model System.DateTime?
@(Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("M/d/yyyy H:mm") : "Undefined")
```

and you would call it:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Created)
```

This would avoid having to specify it everywhere you need it. This will change the default format for ALL dates. If you don't want to do that, it is probably still worth using a template even if you only use it twice or more, so that you can change it in one place if necessary. In that case, change the template name to something like 'ShortDateTime' and call it like this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Created, "ShortDateTime")
```